# Match (lookup) under Matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, match, data-manipulation

I have a matrix,

```
set.seed(100)
x <- matrix(sample(11, 110, replace = T), nrow = 11)
```

and another matrix,

```
y <- cbind(1:11, sample(110, 11))
```

I want to match each element of `x` with the first column of `y`. If matches should return the second column of `y` else `0`. The final out put should have same dimension as `x`.

I tried to do this with `for-loop` with 3 nested loops, but is there any efficient way for this?

The Expected output is

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   26   85    4   40   96    9    4   21   26    21
 [2,]    9   26   21   75    4   88  103   85   21    26
 [3,]   96  103  103   85   21    9    9   88   85   103
 [4,]   93   21   88   88   85   96   75    4    9    93
 [5,]    4   75   21   96    9    9  103   96   26    26
 [6,]    4    9   85   40   26    4   26   40  103    96
 [7,]   21   26   96   88   26   75   96   40   85    75
 [8,]  103   26   26   26    9   40   40   93  103    40
 [9,]   96   75    4   85    9   75   75   96    4    75
[10,]   88    4   40   21   26  103   96   21   88    93
[11,]   96   75   26   85   96   26   85    9   93     4
```

Comment: Add a `set.seed` to your code with the corresponding output.

Comment: I am sorry, I will edit the question

Comment: @TheRimalaya There is no zero in the matrix of your expected output. Could you include a case where your condition to "return the second column of y else 0" is applied?

Comment: That is because, each element of `x` has matched with the first column of `y`

Comment: Oh' yes it is working. Thanks @Rhertel, I didn't saw `<<-` operator, but It is replacing the old one, is it possible to get an newer matrix. or should I make a copy before running this. Anyway, thank you very much. This will work fine for me

Comment: @TheRimalaya I think that it might be the easiest to copy the matrix prior to the transformation in order to preserve the original. I could include this in the answer, but I'm sure that you can handle this.

Comment: See, also, `array(y[, 2L][match(x, y[, 1L])], dim(x))`; you could replace any resulting `NA`s (because of no match) with 0s after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
x[!x%in%y[,1]] <- 0 # set all elements to zero which are not in first column of y
sapply(1:nrow(y),function(i) x[x==y[i,1]] <<- y[i,2]) #replace all matches with second column of y
#> x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   26   85    4   40   96   21    4   21   26    21
# [2,]   21   26   21   75    4   88  103   85   21    26
# [3,]   96  103  103   85   21   21   21   88   85   103
# [4,]   93   21   88   88   85   96   75    4   21    93
# [5,]    4   75   21   96   21   21  103   96   26    26
# [6,]    4   21   85   40   26    4   26   40  103    96
# [7,]   21   26   96   88   26   75   96   40   85    75
# [8,]  103   26   26   26   21   40   40   93  103    40
# [9,]   96   75    4   85   21   75   75   96    4    75
#[10,]   88    4   40   21   26  103   96   21   88    93
#[11,]   96   75   26   85   96   26   85   21   93     4
```

Answer (score 0):

A proposition using `replace`:

```
x2 <- matrix(0, nrow(x), ncol(x))
ind <- unlist(sapply(1:11, function(el) which(x == el) ))
val <- unlist(sapply(1:11, function(el) rep(y[el,2], sum(x == el)) ))
replace(x2, ind, val)
```

Comment: I could not get what I wanted, I will update the question for the expected output